# Xcode 7.2 - unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6.3, xcode7.2

I am migrating from xcode 6.2 to xcode 7.2 and while i am trying to Archive my app to upload build i got this error

```
Ld /Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProjectName normal arm64
    cd "/Users/dev8/Documents/Project Name Main source/ProjectName"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AFNetworking -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FrameAccessor -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage -L/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/iCloudDocumentSync -F/Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/dev8/Documents/Project \Name\ Main\ source/ProjectName/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/dev8/Documents/Project\Name\ Main\ source/ProjectName/Pods/Fabric/iOS -filelist /Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProjectName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lFrameAccessor -lMBProgressHUD -lSDWebImage -lc++ -liCloudDocumentSync -lz -framework CoreGraphics -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lPods-ProjectName -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProjectName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dev8/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bejajbyerkuriqcsjyshbezlexsd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProjectName
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: What the heck is `Xcode 2.app`? You might want to use `Xcode.app`...

Comment: Xcode 2 is xcode version xcode7.2

Comment: I'd recommend naming it properly to Xcode.app and removing the old version...

Comment: ok thanks i will check and let you know the status

Comment: One more thing to note — make sure you are using the current command line tools for your version as well. `Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command-Line Tools > Xcode 7.2`

Comment: I remove the older version and change command line tool, still i am facing the issue

Comment: Same exact error? I'm guessing you've still got some version 6 items still messing with version 7. I would re-download Xcode 7.2 and start fresh perhaps. Also be sure the clean your project before building...

Comment: I update the Enable Bitcode "Yes" to "No". It works perfectly

Comment: Great! and you've got Xcode in proper order as well :)